# Redirect in form.parse doesn't work for me

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, formidable

I used formidable to parse form, which posts image and files with related info.
Here is my code snippet.

```
router.post('/create', passport.parseForm, (req, res) => {     
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
            templates = {
                 name: fields.name,
                 title: fields.title
            } ;
            templates.create(template, (err, id) => {
               if (err || !id) {
                req.flash('danger', err);
                return res.redirect('/campaigns/create?' + 'type=note');
               }
               var campaign = fields;
               campaign.template = id;
               campaigns.create(campaign, false, (err, id) => {
               if (err || !id) {
                   req.flash('danger', err);
                   return res.redirect('/campaigns/create?type=note');
               }
               req.flash('success', 'Object Created');
               res.redirect(('/campaigns/edit/' + id);
             });
        });
    }
```

I expected page will be redirected to another page after message "Object Created" if it doesn't occur any error, but the page doesn't redirect and any message isn't displayed.
And it prints the HTML code of the page which should be redirected to in the console.

Is this something you faced before? What's wrong here?